# Removing deleted files from TFS 2012 Source Control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, source-control-explorer

I am having issues trying to mark files as 'Delete' that have been deleted from my local machine by an application. The issue is that these files no longer exist so TFS will not process them as 'Deleted'.

I have downloaded the TFS 2012 Power Tools and tried to run 'tfpt.exe online /deletes /recrusive ' but this simply gives me a list of folders that these missing files sit in, not a list of each and every file themselves. This means that when I click 'Pend changes' I get the following error message for each command -

"One or more children have pending changes".

My question is, is anyone aware of a method I can use to carry out this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `tfpt online` is detecting that *the folders* have been deleted.  It is trying to pend a delete on those folders, but it sounds like you have already pended different changes on the files within those folders.

`tfpt online` will not pend a deletion of the folders if you have other changes pended for its children.

If you want to delete the folders, undo the pending changes on their children, make sure that the contents on-disk match what you want, then re-run `tfpt online`.

Comment: I initially did this but I am having to do this in chunks due to our folder structure in the solution. I am looking to do it in one go but I can't see any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If there's not too many files you could run the destroy command in Visual Studio Command Prompt.

> Destroys, or permanently deletes, version-controlled items from Team
>   Foundation version control.

**Command**

```
tf destroy $/MyProject/Files/123.cs /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/myproject
```

Comment: This is a really big hammer to bring out, and it also won't fix his pending changes problem.  If anything, it will be worse since he will now have conflicts with a destroyed item.

Comment: +1 Yeah I agree now, also after reading back on the OP's question. I don't believe my answer to this is what he was looking for at all.

Comment: Destroy just always scares me.  :)